Finding a vector with positive quadratic form
Given a real matrix $J$, how would one find a real vector $v$ such that $v^TJv>0$?
If $J$ is Hermitian (self-adjoint) $J=\bar{J}^T$, then the eigenvalues are real, and this can be done by finding the eigenvectors associated with positive eigenvalues. Even if only one of the eigenvalues is real and positive, the associated eigenvector will qualify as such $v$.
However, I am interested in the complementary case, where all the eigenvalues of $J$ have a negative real part. I wish to find such a $v$ or know that no such $v$ exists.
Is there an analytical or numerical method to do so?

Clearly, it is false. For example, $J=-1$ is a $1\times1$ matrix.

@GuyangHuan so for $J=-1$ no such vector exists, it's fine per my definition.

If you just want to find such a real vector. Notice that $v^TJv = \sum_{i,j=1}^nv_iJ_{ij}v_j = v^T\frac{J+J^T}{2}v$. It means such a vector $v$ exists if and only if the Hermitian matrix $J+J^T$ has a negative eigenvalue $\lambda$. Moreover, $v$ satisfies $(J+J^T)v=\lambda v$.

@GuyangHuan this fully answers my question

On the one hand, we assumed all the eigenvalues of $J$ have a negative real part; on the other hand:
$$0<v^TJv=v^TJv/2+v^TJ^Tv/2=v^T(\frac{J+J^T}{2})v$$
where $\frac{J+J^T}{2}$ is real and symmetric and hence have only real eigenvalues, so any eigenvector associated with a positive eigenvalue would satisfy the requirement from the question.
Moreover, if all the eigenvalues of $\frac{J+J^T}{2}$ are negative such $v$ cannot be found (e.g., because the Rayleigh quotient of this matrix is bounded between the largest and smallest eigenvalues).
